# Маршрутизация запросов к микросервисам

Tags: nginx, golang, маршрутизация, микросервисы

Существует сервис с "кучей" контроллеров. Стоит задача "распилить" данный сервис на микросервисы.

Сами микросервисы будут крутится на самостоятельных машинах.

Основная проблема в том, что есть некий роут(http://mydomain/myservice/srv/data), на который приходит разного типа запросы.

А логика после вызывается на основании значения в поле запроса. То есть два запроса на получение name и balance должны уходить на разные логики будующих микросервисов(получение имени должно перенаправится, к примеру, на http://mydomain/myservice1/data/name, а получение баланса на http://mydomain/myservice2/data/balance ).

По факту сейчас вижу такие решения(если они возможны, конечно):

Анализ на точке входа(ngix)
Написание сервиса-маршрутизатора(анализирует и, грубо говоря, перенаправляет запросы RestTemplate'ом, к примеру, на микросервисы)
Вопрос: какие штатные средства есть для анализа содержимого тела запроса и дальнейшего перенаправления на другой микросервис?

Очень не хочется городить "велосипед" с п.2

Может есть какие либо библиотеки для подобных целей, где можно лаконично это реализовать, к примеру.

UPD: рассматриваются и легковестные библиотеки, с помощью которых можно реализовать такой роутинг, основанный на содержимом тела запроса. Т.к. дали ясно понять, что вариант с настройкой ngix - крайний

Comment: Между сервисами NATS. А для фронта Nginx.

Comment: Как правило между микросервисами, то что не торчит наружу, общение организовывается через какое-нибудь QQ: RabbitMQ, NATS или что-то ещё. Т.е. есть сервер который принимает запросы от-до и складывает их в очередь и отправляет всем подписаным на очередь. Вот и вся маршрутизация. Общение через nginx идёт между фронтом и бэком, но не между микросервисами бэка. Микросервисы общяются между собой через "очереди сообщений".

Comment: Хороший совет использовать очереди. благодарю. Каким образом настроить так чтобы при заходе в карточку товара создавалась очередь сразу на несколько микросервисы одновременно? Например при запросе карточки товара, мне нужно сервис Склада запросить о наличии товара и Сервис доставки запросить о доступной дате доставки и стоимости доставки и например Сервис отзывов о товаре запросить. Как в таком случае поступить?

Comment: Сервисы подключаются к NATS-серверу и сразу, при старте, подписываются на свои очереди, типа, back.storage.*, back.delivery.*,back.feedback.*. Потом сервис, который их запрашивает отправляет в каждую из очередей (это может быть и вложенная очередь, не суть) свои сообщения и ждёт ответов. У NATS есть возможность запроса-ответа. И просто ждёт ответов. А потом их объединяет.

Comment: Т.е. они все, или все у которых можно что-то запросить по сути со старта имеют свои готовые очереди на сервере. А дальше просто запрос-ответ. Так делаются микросервисы